# Gnuplot Animate multiple figures from data file

Tags: animation, gnuplot

I have a data file containing *n* coordinate positions at *t* time steps of *c* number of figures which I would like to create an animation of in a gif file using gnuplot.

The data file is setup giving the *n* coordinate positions of all *c* figures at each time step, as

```
x1,1 y1,1
x1,2 y1,2
.
.
.
x1,n y1,n
x2,1 y2,1
.
.
.
xc,n yc,n
```

At each time step, I want to plot all *n* positions of my *c* figures in my gif animation.

The following code isn't exactly working.

```
set terminal gif animate
set output "output.gif"

do for [i=1:time_final] {
do for [j=1:c] {
plot "file.dat" every 1::(i-1)*(j-1)*n::i*j*n-1 u 1:2 w filledcurves
}}
set output
```

I apologize for the newbie-ness of this question.

Comment: Please read up on [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on StackOverflow. More specifically, show us what you have tried, and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post following your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the `every` statement needs a small adjustment. Each of your "time steps" contains in total `c*n` records. Point numbers in Gnuplot in the context of `every` keyword are 0-based. This means that time-step `i` (assuming that the first one has `i=1` as in your `do` loop) begins at point `(i-1)*c*n`. In order to move to "figure" `j` (assuming again that the first one within each time step has `j=1`), we need to add an offset of `(j-1)*n`. Now, since each "figure" has `n` points, the offset of the last point within each figure is `n-1`. In total:

```
do for [i=1:time_final] {
    stepOffset = (i-1)*c*n
    do for [j=1:c] {
        firstPoint = stepOffset + (j-1)*n
        lastPoint = firstPoint + (n-1)
        plot "file.dat" every ::firstPoint::lastPoint u 1:2 w filledcurves
}}
```

In case you would want to merge the `c` "figures" into one plot, you could do:

```
do for [i=1:2] {
    stepOffset = (i-1)*c*n
    plot for [j=1:c] "file.dat" every ::(stepOffset + (j-1)*n)::(stepOffset + (j-1)*n + (n-1)) u 1:2 w filledcurves
}
```

By the way, since your data file has only two columns, the `w filledcurves` style seems to be misplaced here, if you want to fill the area between the curve and for example x-axis, `w filledcurves x1` should work...

Comment: Works great, thank you very much! Just maybe edit in your second piece of code "do for [i=i:2]" to "do for [i=1:time_final]" In regards to your comment about "filledcurves," in fact what I am plotting are the coordinate position of closed figures so "filledcurves" colors inside my figures.